# Which svg-library is compatible with interact.js?

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to have a drag&drop field on my website with draggable elements, some of them exported from adobe illustrator and embedded as img, some created with an svg library like svg.js, because they have to be modifiable. I'm looking for a way to move both in the same field.

I tried to use the code of the first example (Dragging) from the website http://interactjs.io/ on this svg.js-generated element:

```
<body>
  <div id="drawing" class="draggable"></div> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.5.0/svg.js"></script>
  <script>
    var draw = SVG('drawing').size(400,400);
    draw.rect(130, 30).attr({'x': 30, 'y': 80, 'fill': 'black'});
  </script>
</body>
```

Interact.js can move the img elements nicely, but not the elements generated by svg.js. I can only move the rectangle on the y-axis and the whole right side of the page next to the rectangle becomes draggable.

Is it possible to work on both embedded and code-generated svg with the same js-library? Or should I use two libraries? At the end I need the coordinates of the elements on the field.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example dragging svg elements. It does not need a library.  It also handles elements that have been previously transformed before the drag/drop is implemented on an element.
Each svg element that you want to drag needs only to include the class="dragTarget". This can be added in any element.
Try the example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Drag SVG</title>
</head>
<body>
 SVG Drag/Drop is also applied to previously transformed elements (see maroon rectangle).
<div style=background:gainsboro;width:300px;height:300px>
<svg id="mySVG" width="300" height="300"  onmousedown="startDrag(evt)" onmousemove="drag(evt)" onmouseup="endDrag()">
<circle style=cursor:move class="dragTarget" id="redCircle" cx="90" cy="80" r="30" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" style="cursor:default" ></circle>
<circle style=cursor:move class="dragTarget" id="orangeCircle" cx="200" cy="200" r="20" fill="orange" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" ></circle>
<rect style=cursor:move transform="translate(100,100)scale(1.2,.8)" class="dragTarget" id="maroonRect" x="120" y="150" width="30" height="30" fill="maroon" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></rect>
<rect style=cursor:move class="dragTarget" id="blueRect" x="40" y="60" width="30" height="15" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></rect>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
var TransformRequestObj
var TransList
var DragTarget=null;
var Dragging = false;
var OffsetX = 0;
var OffsetY = 0;
//---mouse down over element---
function startDrag(evt)
{
 if(!Dragging) //---prevents dragging conflicts on other draggable elements---
 {
  if(evt.target.getAttribute("class")=="dragTarget")
  {
   DragTarget = evt.target;
   //---reference point to its respective viewport--
   var pnt = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
   pnt.x = evt.clientX;
   pnt.y = evt.clientY;
   //---elements transformed and/or in different(svg) viewports---
   var sCTM = DragTarget.getScreenCTM();
   var Pnt = pnt.matrixTransform(sCTM.inverse());

   TransformRequestObj = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransform()
   //---attach new or existing transform to element, init its transform list---
   var myTransListAnim=DragTarget.transform
   TransList=myTransListAnim.baseVal

   OffsetX = Pnt.x
   OffsetY = Pnt.y

   Dragging=true;
  }
 }
}
//---mouse move---
function drag(evt)
{
 if(Dragging)
 {
  var pnt = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
  pnt.x = evt.clientX;
  pnt.y = evt.clientY;
  //---elements in different(svg) viewports, and/or transformed ---
  var sCTM = DragTarget.getScreenCTM();
  var Pnt = pnt.matrixTransform(sCTM.inverse());
  Pnt.x -= OffsetX;
  Pnt.y -= OffsetY;

  TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Pnt.x,Pnt.y)
  TransList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
  TransList.consolidate()
 }
}
//--mouse up---
function endDrag()
{
 Dragging = false ;

}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll definitely have a look at your solution. I accidentally figured out the solution for the first problem between svg.js and interact.js. Every html element needs to have a defined width and height, otherwise not draggable properly with interact.js.